# Batch split text file to text files at where a string occurs

Tags: batch-file, text, split

I have a 2GB text file which I want to split to N-th text files at where a string " split please here`" occurs. The symbol` is very important!

How to do that quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `awk` installed, you can do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{f=1}/split please here`/{f++;next}{print >"out"f".txt"}' file
```

and your output files will be called out1.txt, out2.txt, out3.txt

You can get `awk` for Windows [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net).